# UIAlertController background color iOS10

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, ios10, uialertcontroller

Code that I wrote for iOS9, worked really well:

```
UIAlertController* alert = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"Select source"
                                                                   message:nil
                                                            preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleActionSheet];
    alert.view.backgroundColor = DARK_BLUE;
    alert.view.tintColor = NEON_GREEN;
    UIView *subview = alert.view.subviews.firstObject;
    UIView *alertContentView = subview.subviews.firstObject;
    alertContentView.backgroundColor = DARK_BLUE;
    alertContentView.layer.cornerRadius = 10;
```

My point of view is that `UIAlertController` is inheriting from `UIViewController`, and `UIViewController` have property `UIView` that can be changed. And this is working. Now, that view inherited from `UIViewController` have it's own subview that is contentView showed as Alert. I can access it as firstObject in array of subviews. Now, why message for sending background color isn't working anymore? Do anyone know some new solution?

Comment: Thank you for answer, but explanation here is same, accessing content view from subviews array. It shows now yellow blurred color. Not original.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**For everyone that will bump into the same problem, I've found the solution:**

`UIAlertController.view` contains one subview, that is only *container*.

*That subview contains subview that contains two it's own subviews*, **one is container**, and another is layer for blurring it.

So, it needs for in loop to iterate through that two subviews and change background color of both.

Full code:

```
UIAlertController* alert = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"Select source"
                                                                   message:nil
                                                            preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleActionSheet];
    alert.view.tintColor = NEON_GREEN;

    UIView *firstSubview = alert.view.subviews.firstObject;

    UIView *alertContentView = firstSubview.subviews.firstObject;
    for (UIView *subSubView in alertContentView.subviews) { //This is main catch
        subSubView.backgroundColor = DARK_BLUE; //Here you change background
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

In Swift 3.0

```
let FirstSubview = alertController.view.subviews.first
    let AlertContentView = FirstSubview?.subviews.first
    for subview in (AlertContentView?.subviews)! {
        subview.backgroundColor = UIColor.black
        subview.layer.cornerRadius = 10
        subview.alpha = 1
        subview.layer.borderWidth = 1
        subview.layer.borderColor = UIColor.yellow.cgColor
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I use this:

```
    UIAlertController *alert = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"Alert!"
                                                                       message:@"Message of alert"
                                                                 preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];

        UIAlertAction* defaultAction = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Ok" 
                                                                style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
                                                              handler:^(UIAlertAction * action) {

                                                                  //Your code
                                                              }];
        [alert addAction:defaultAction];

        UIView * topview = alert.view.subviews.firstObject;
        UIView * colorView = topview.subviews.firstObject;
        colorView.backgroundColor = [UIColor yellowColor];
        colorView.layer.cornerRadius = 10;
        [self presentViewController:alert animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Comment: Sorry, but the approach is pretty same as sample code of mine. And I tried it, it shows yellow color, but blurred, I need original.

Comment: Then I suggest you to implement your custom uialertcontroller, faster way

Comment: I've found the solution, check my own answer, it could help if you bump into the same problem.