# Change UIAlertController background color and text font & color with Swift 4

Tags: swift, xcode, fonts, colors, uialertcontroller

I want to change the background of my Alert Controller to match the background of my game and the text font to match the text font of my game here is the code i'm using and isn't working

```
    let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Time Up!", message: "Your time is up! You got a score of \(point) points and your total coins now is \(totalPoints). You Can Do Better", preferredStyle: .alert)

            let restartAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Play Again!", style: .default, handler: nil)
            alertController.addAction(restartAction)

            alertController.view.tintColor = UIColor(red: 226, green: 158, blue: 152, alpha: 1.0 )
            alertController.view.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 226, green: 158, blue: 152, alpha: 1.0)
            alertController.view.layer.cornerRadius = 15

            self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: try something as suggested in this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39852020/uialertcontroller-background-color-ios10

Comment: Many customization code for `UIAlertController` depends on the implementation details which is not officially documented. Such codes may work in some iOS versions, may or may not work in other versions including future updates. I would write my own view controller for alert and show it modally, instead of hacking the implementation details of the current `UIAlertController`.

Comment: Thanks @Deepika This helped change background but I still need font!

Comment: Anyway you could direct me into doing this? @OOPer

Comment: @Lz_Cole, In this thread you are asking how to customize `UIAlertController`, and I would not like to show some fragile code depending on implementation details. If you want to ask how you can show your own view controller like alert, you should start another thread, or you may find some related threads already existing in SO. Anyway, it's your choice.

Answer (score 0):

Alert Controller is default iOS controller. You can create your custom view. Add labels, buttons and apply colour theme on that.

Or there are third party libraries, you can use that.

https://github.com/dinhquan/SwiftAlertView

https://github.com/Hamadakram/AlertView

Answer (score -1):

In changing UIAlertController `background color` you need to do it like this:

```
alertController.view
    .subviews.first?
    .subviews.first?
    .subviews.first?
    .backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 226/255.0, green: 158/255.0, blue: 152/255.0, alpha: 1.0)
```

And also in setting RGB UIColor you must include **/255** to work. Example:

```
UIColor(red: 226/255.0, green: 158/255.0, blue: 152/255.0, alpha: 1.0)
```

Comment: Thank you this is the most help Ive received yet! Any chance if its possible to change the text font on it?

Comment: For AlertController (title & message):

1. Create a font attribute, here we use font **Rockwell**:
 let font = [NSAttributedString.Key.font: UIFont(name: "Rockwell", size: 12.0)]

2. Create NSMutableAttributedString:
 let textAttributedstring = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "Text", attributes: titleFont)

3. Set title via NSMUtableAttributedString:
 alertController.setValue(textAttributedstring, forKey: "attributedTitle") // just change to **attributedMessage** in forKey if message